# 'Find Usages' IDE functionality for Angularjs (Directives, Services)

Tags: angularjs, ide

I'm starting to wonder what is the best way to work with a moderately sized AngularJS project. I'm wanting to find where a directive or service is used without having to do a 'Ctrl+F' and search the project manually. Are there any IDEs that offer this feature, or does anyone have some approaches for working with these projects that they could share?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it personally, so my answer is going to be pretty short, but I think you should look at TypeScript (http://www.typescriptlang.org/). I've seen many mentions of it being a good fit for Angular, and it allows for "Intellisense" features in IDE that should meet your needs.

Basically it means rewriting your code in an "augmented" version of JavaScript that makes your code typed and therefore should make it easier to handle a large codebase and run static analysis.

Here's some information about TypeScript support in IntelliJ, if that's your IDE: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/typescript-support.html

Comment: Interesting idea, I'm just a bit apprehensive about writing in an augmented language. Thanks though.